# Table data update on input change

Tags: jquery

I want to change the table data on input radio change
Please check JSFiddle link in the comment with example.

By default, the table show array values for

Plan A ==> `cashData, invoiceData and expenseData`

But I want to table data to change on input radio plan B click, 
the table should show

Plan B ==> `cashData2, invoiceData2 and expenseData2` 
and on clicking plan C, table should show total of

Plan C ==> `cashData+cashData2, invoiceData+invoiceData2, expenseData+expenseData2`
how to change table data on input radio switch?

Comment: Here is the code link http://jsfiddle.net/3ca9vzou/7/

Comment: ReferenceError: `cd,id and cashTotal` are not defined

Comment: if I replace 
  for (var i = 0; i < cashData.length / 8; i++) {

with 
  for (var i = 0; i < cd.length / 8; i++) {
it doesnt work

Comment: So if you click on Plan A must show Cash, if Plan B must show Invoice and if Plan C Expensive?

Comment: row 1 - CashData
row 2  - invoiceData
row 3 - expenseData

On input change, say plan B
row1 - cashData2
row2 - invoiceData2
row3 - expenseData2

Comment: any know how to change table data on input radio switch?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal This looks like a homework to me..

Comment: @Bani please check my answer and accepet it ,if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have already the required function to built your table.

Just add the required parameters to your function --> what arrays to use to built the table, and then simply switch the arrays in your `change` function.

For the last case pass the summ of arrays as parameters, and do not forget to empty your table each time before inserting new html to it.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ebjjpk6/2/)